# Mid-band magnitude gain of a Cascode Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, cascode

Looking to do some theoretical analysis on a Cascode Amplifier and compare it to a simulated model. Please see the circuit schematic below followed by the bode plot developed in the simulation software:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: Bode Plot]

I am looking to try and obtain the Mid-band frequency gain of the amplifier (From the bode plot it can be seen to be approximately 20 dB). Any help in trying to figure this out would be greatly appreciated - so far compared Quiescent Levels which appear to match theoretical values.

[image]

Comment: The voltage gain should be equal to about gm*Rc||RL = 75V/V = 37dB if Ic current is around 0.8mA. But because you have very high RS the gain will be much lower. IF the beta is around 150 the gain will be reduced by (R1||R2||(β/gm))/(Rs + R1||R2||(β/gm)) = 0.15 therefore the overall voltage gain is 75V/V * 0.15 = 11V/V = 21dB

Comment: @G36 apologies forgot to mention Beta is 200 - but I understand the process. However, can you clarify where gm*Rc||RL = 75V/V comes from? From my calculation gm*Rc||RL would work out to be approximately between 2&3 taking V_T as 25mV? Is this method incorrect?

Comment: What is Ic current ?

Comment: gm = 0.8mA/25mV = 32mS and Rc||RL = 2.5kΩ therefore Av = 32mS*2.5kΩ = 80V/V = 38dB

Comment: @G36 Ic is 796 micro amps - resulting in approximately 38dB as you mentioned. However, this is almost double the gain seen in the simulation?

Comment: But as I already said the overall gain will be lower due to high Rs resistance and low Rin of an amplifier. Av = (R1||R2||(β/gm))/(Rs + R1||R2||(β/gm)) *  gm*Rc||RL = 0.16*80 = 13 V/V = 22dB

Comment: Ok, is there any link or information regarding the derivation of this gain? Specifically since it is the Mid-Band frequency gain - just interested in how you arrived at that / how one would obtain this.

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I found it by Inspection. But you can use a small-signal analysis if you want. Can you do it?

Comment: @G36 I appended my small-signal circuit but cannot see how one would obtain the mid-band frequency. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why RE is not "shorted" GND via Ce capacitor?

Comment: Mistake - apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this small-signal diagram

[image]

We clearly see a voltage divider at the input.

Therefore 
$$\frac{V_{B1}}{V_S} = \frac{R_1||R_2||(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}}{R_S + R_1||R_2||(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}}$$

Next, let us find the first stage voltage gain (Q1). This stage is working as a CE ( common-emitter) amplifier.

$$V_{B1} = I_B\cdot(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}$$

$$V_{C1} = - I_{C1} \cdot r_{e2} = I_B \cdot \beta_1 \cdot r_{e2}$$

$$\frac{V_{C1}}{V_{B1}} = -\frac{I_B \cdot \beta_1 \cdot r_{e2}}{I_B\cdot(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}} = -\frac{r_{e2}}{r_{e1}} \cdot \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_1 +1} = -\alpha \frac{r_{e2}}{r_{e1}} $$

Now we can find the second stage gain (Q2) that works as a CB (common-base) amplifier.

$$V_O = - I_{C2} \cdot R_C||R_L =-\alpha_2 I_{E2} R_C||R_L = -I_{C1} R_C||R_L \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1} $$

$$V_{C1} = - I_{C1}\times r_{e2}$$

$$\frac{V_O}{V_{C1}} = \frac{-I_{C1} R_C||R_L \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1}}{- I_{C1}\times r_{e2}} = \frac{R_C||R_L}{r_{e2}} \times \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1}$$

And finally, the overall voltage gain \$\frac{V_O}{V_S}\$ is

$$\frac{V_O}{V_S} = - \frac{R_1||R_2||(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}}{R_S + R_1||R_2||(\beta_1 +1)r_{e1}} \times\frac{r_{e2}}{r_{e1}}\times\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_1 +1}\times\frac{R_C||R_L}{r_{e2}} \times \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1}  $$

Any additional questions?

Comment: And this is the mid-band gain? Just by analysing the SSEC?

Comment: Yes, this is the mid-band voltage gain. What have you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the Rsource from 10,000 ohms to 50 ohms.

If the bipolar runs at 1mA, if the diode (emitter-base junction) "ideality factor" ==1, and if the bipolar beta is 100, then the input resistance is

26 ohms * 100 = 2,600 ohms.

With Rsource of 10,000 ohms, a 14 db (5:1) attenuation exists.

Comment: The value mentioned is specified - unless you're suggesting to change it for the purpose of the analysis?

Comment: @BrandonKellett you have 20 dB gain instead of 40 dB because only half the voltage gets applied to the base. Rs and R1 form a voltage divider. An amplifier with a voltage input needs to have high input impedance.