Cascode transistor small signal analysis
I could not find a similar question on stack exchange and I need pretty urgent help.

I am confused about how to represent this circuit using small signal model for the transistors. Particularly R2, would it be in parallel with r0 (Q2) or be connected to ground. Assuming that R2 is not significantly smaller than r0.
Also would there be any small signal collector and emitter current since there is no small signal input to Q2?
Thanks. I will appreciate any clarification.

If this is homework it should be tagged as such.  Are you sure about the value of V3?

Have you looked here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/489944/mid-band-magnitude-gain-of-a-cascode-amplifier/490116#490116 As for a tip, simple short to GND V4 and V3. You will see that R2 is connected to the ground as well as Q2 base.

my bad I did not know that there was a homework tag, it is not a directly my homework question. I am confused about a concept that I need to answer it.

What small-signal model do you prefer? A hybrid-pi or T-model?

The equivalent circuit of an active electrical network (for example a voltage amplifier), for small signals or incremental signals and for frequencies in the middle of the band, is obtained by replacing all independent constant voltage generators (the power supplies) with a short circuit and opening the current ones if there are any. The transistors in turn must be replaced with their equivalent circuits which can be those with h or hybrid parameters, or other parameters.

In practice V3 should be higher than 0.7V - as shown the collector voltage of Q1 will be close to zero. V3 should be 2-3V minimum.
